# Cast to generic interface dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an external function which has following syntax:

```
public void Set<FieldType>(
    Field field,
FieldType value
)
```

Field type can be some of primitive types like **int**, **double**, **bool** etc. and also can be generic list of these types, e.g. **IList< int >**

The problem is that I must pass exactly an *IList< T >* interface. If I pass any type which implements *IList< T >* interface the function throws **InvalidOperationException** *Unsupported type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]*

For example:

```
IList<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

Entity entity = new Entity();

//this works fine
entity.Set(field, list1);

//Here exception is throw
entity.Set(field, list2);

//works fine as well
entity.Set(field, list2 as IList<int>);
```

The issue that I get the list dynamically via reflection

```
var property = entityType.GetProperty(field.FieldName);
dynamic propertyValue = property.GetValue(myObject, null);
```

So, the propertyValue is *List< T >*, not a *IList< T >*, and when I pass this value to the external functions I see an exception.

Obviously, it is a bug of external function.

The only idea I have is to cast the propertyValue to *IList< T >*. **But I don't know T at the compile time**.

So, I need to cast dynamically. I've got a generic list interface type like variable

```
var genericIListType = typeof (IList<>)
    .MakeGenericType(field.ValueType);
```

But I cannot find the way how to cast propertyValue to this type. I can find only examples how to cast object to other objects (e.g. using *Activator.CreateInstance*), but I need to cast to an interface.

Please give me advice how to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the external function:

```
public void SetWrapper<T>(Field field, List<T> list) {
    entity.Set(field, (IList<T>)list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. The solution is even more simple than you suggested: public static void SetWrapper<T>(this Entity entity, Field field, IList<T> value)
        {            
            entity.Set(field, value);
        }